# How can I display images with the Codeigniter php framework?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How can I display images with the Codeigniter php framework?

I want to fetch an image from the `images` folder inside `views`.

I used this code in one of the `views` php files:

```
<img border="0" src="images/hed_05.jpg" width="61" height="133">
```

But it is not working.

Comment: I think questions like these get closed way too easily.

Answer (score 22):

Images, css, javascript, pdfs, xml... anything that is allowed to be accessed **directly** should not be living in your application directory. You *can* do it, but you really shouldn't. Create a new folder at the root of your directory for these files, they should not be mixed into your application, for example: in your `views` folder.

1. Chances are, you're using an .htaccess file, which is only allowing certain directories to be accessed via http. This is very good for security reasons, you want to stop any attempt to access your controllers and models directly. This is also why we check if `BASEPATH` is defined at the top of most files, and `exit('No direct script access.')` if not.
2. To get the correct path to these resources (js/css/images), you can't use relative paths, because we aren't using a normal directory structure. The url `/users/login` is not loading files from the directory `/users/login`, it probably doesn't even exist. These are just uri segments that the bootstrap uses to know which class, method, and params to use.

To get the correct path, either use a forward slash (assuming your app and assets are in the root directory, not a subdirectory) like this:

```
<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" />
```

Or your best bet, use an absolute url:

```
// References your $config['base_url']
<img src="<?php echo site_url('images/myimage.jpg'); ?>" />
```

Equivalent to:

```
<img src="http://mydomain.com/images/myimage.jpg" />
```

There are helpers built into CI that you can optionally use as well, but this is really all you need to know.

Comment: moving my `images` directory From the `applications` directory up to the root directory solved it for me ...

Answer (score 9):

Please see the [CI User Guide/HTML Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img) img() tag:

```
echo img('images/picture.jpg');
// gives <img src="http://site.com/images/picture.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just set your `base href` in the `<head>`:

`<base href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" />`

Now any image, css file and other asset will be relative to your base URL.

`<base href="http://site.com/" />`

`<img src="images/foo.jpg" />`

is in effect

`<img src="http://site.com/images/foo.jpg" />`

Your images should be outside of the application folder (say in `/images`) however.

Comment: Adding this into the head resulted in a completely blank page. :(

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the path in the `src` attribute is incorrect. Maybe try

```
<img border="0" src="/images/hed_05.jpg" width="61" height="133">
```

Comment: It will be useless only if your images folder doesn't live in the base folder (it shouldn't be in your view folder). Galen is correct with the above code