# define custom variables and direct call the variables in view part

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I want to do is creating a file like `my_custom_settings.php` in `config` directory and call the defined variable in view part.

let's say in `my_custom_settings.php`:

```
define('TEMPLATE_DIR', 'assets/front');
```

and in view part direct in HTML:

```
<link href="<?=TEMPLATE_DIR?>/stylesheet/style.css">
```

or any other alternative solution??

**PS:** Now I am using `base_url()` to access the path

Comment: base _url is best way to do it....why you want to do like that.....

Comment: @Venkat i just want to define some images directories, and i saw somewhere in a codeigniter project. Is there any issue with to access the path with `defined variable`??

Comment: so u want use some images in you are application. For that you want to create a directory and you want to call that directory by defining a custom variable.......am i right

Comment: @Venkat yes, something like `<img src="<?=IMG_PATH?>/images/user.jpg">`

Comment: do one thing no need to create any variable.......just create a directory in your application_name->application and Images.......Now you can include any name just like this base_url/images/imge.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally i extend the /core/helpers/url_helper.php , defaults are `site_url() , base_url(), current_url();` etc ... i just extended that for having `base_static_url();`

so put in core/helpers/url_helper.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists('base_static_url'))
{
    function base_static_url()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->slash_item('base_static_url');
    }
}
```

then in config.php file you just add 1 more line:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://mysite.com/";
$config['base_static_url'] = "http://mysite.com/static/"; //path to your static resources folder
```

then you can call static resources using :

```
<img src="<?php echo base_static_url();?>img/myimage.png"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i appreciate with your answer but i already defined `base_url()` in my application, but i just want to know if it's according to my question, cause i saw somewhere in a codeigniter project, i know i don't have specific reason to use defined variable, if it's wrong then please make me correct.

Comment: you can both use a constant or extend the url_helper.php me i preferr extending the url_helper.php cause that is the one is setting the base_url,the current_url, the site_url and so on, so i think is better having all in 1 file

Comment: doesn't matter if you just have base_url() you can set others easly if you do what i told you to do :)

Answer (score 1):

ok this is might be more then what you are looking for, 
but this is a way to put site wide configs in one file, and then easily have them available

in config folder you have file: my_custom_settings.php

in that file you want to set a config value like:

```
$config['TEMPLATE_DIR'] = 'assets/front' ;
$config['site_slogan'] = 'Laravel? Never heard of it' ;
```

create another file called: My_custom_settings.php

put that file in: application/library/My_custom_settings.php
that file will contain:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class My_custom_settings
{

function __construct($config = array() )
{
foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = $value;    
    }
//  makes it possible for CI to use the load method 
$CI =& get_instance();
//  load the config variables
$CI->load->vars($data);
}
} // end my custom settings
```

now in your controller constructor

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

// Load configs for controller and view
    $this->load->library( 'my_custom_settings' );
    $this->config->load( 'my_custom_settings' );


} // end construct
```

Now for the cool part -- anything you put in that config file, will be available for your controller and views. ( you can load config in a model constructor as well ).

in a controller or model you get the value with $this->config, like

```
$this->config->item( 'site_slogan' )
```

a little awkward, but for views, heres the reward, you only need the config name

```
echo $TEMPLATE_DIR . '/somefile' ;
```

Comment: +1 like your way. i changed my mind to use something like this `TEMPLATE_DIR` because of no reason. Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Images, css, javascript, pdfs, xml... anything that is allowed to be accessed directly should not be living in your application directory. You can do it, but you really shouldn't. Create a new folder at the root of your directory for these files, they should not be mixed into your application, for example: in your views folder.

1. Chances are, you're using an .htaccess file, which is only allowing certain directories to be accessed via http. This is very good for security reasons, you want to stop any attempt to access your controllers and models directly. This is also why we check if BASEPATH is defined at the top of most files, and exit('No direct script access.') if not.
2. To get the correct path to these resources (js/css/images), you can't use relative paths, because we aren't using a normal directory structure. The url /users/login is not loading files from the directory /users/login, it probably doesn't even exist. These are just uri segments that the bootstrap uses to know which class, method, and params to use.
   To get the correct path, either use a forward slash (assuming your app and assets are in the root directory, not a subdirectory) like this:

   [image]
     Or your best bet, use an absolute url:

   // References your $config['base_url']
    " />
    Equivalent to:

   http://mydomain.com/images/myimage.jpg
   There are helpers built into CI that you can optionally use as well, but this is really all you need to know.

Comment: this is wrong if you need to move static resources to another site domain you get a big refactoring trouble!!

Comment: No need just change the folder to another domain directory and access them again using base_url/iamges/imge.jpg. I am working right now in my application. Few days i worked on my local system where  my base_url is localhost/application_name. After that i shifted my application to server so i just changed my base_url it works like a gem.......

Comment: you didn't catched what i tell you, what if you have your **app** on **site.com** and your **img folder** on **othersite.com** ?

Comment: using codeIgniter u can't access resources outside of your application directory..........

Comment: totally wrong :/ i'm talking about static resources (img,js,css) YOU CAN and not only with CI

Comment: me not sincerily, which was your problem? :)

Comment: check out this link Ispuk and Jogesh for more clarity in what i am saying..........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656894/how-can-i-display-images-with-the-codeigniter-php-framework

Comment: ok, but you didn't checked that following what i wrote in answer you totally fix that problem! cause then you'll have separated **base_url()** and **base_static_url()**