# How can I use relative path in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, relative-path

I know a little bit about relative path. Suppose, I have a project on codeigniter. There are 4 controller such as with function name:

```
1. Admin->index,profile,add_student,edit_marks,make_admin,
2. Teacher->index,add_marks,update_marks 
3. Student->index,view_teacher,view_result
4. Guest->index,view_Student, view_marks,view_result
```

From these, How can I use them as relative path ?Remind it,some times I go one controller to another controller, such as profile,view_marks is a common function for all, so every one access it.

For images or file can I use relative path ? Then,Suppose I have a image at root folder as
->root_folder/template/images/a.png. How can I use it as relative path ?

Really, I need the core knowledge of relative path with application in codeigniter.

Comment: Do you mean [URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)?

Comment: @Bora, No,  I mean relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I have found the answer that is:

It is not necessary to use base_url or site_url every times for link.

All time use:

```
 /controller_name/function_name
```

Such as for a anchor link on viewing admins's profile code as(I hope, this technique is called relative path). It decrease time to route it.

```
    <a href="/admin/profile">Admin Profile</a>
```

Comment: It is better and best practice to use the functions provided. If your site/application is ever moved to a subdirectory, all of those links will be broken.

Answer (score 3):

You should use codeigniter constants defined in root/index.php

To get Root path use

> FCPATH

It returns

Path upto root folder where your codeigniter is installed.

So in your case , it will be

> FCPATH . 'template/images/a.png';

I assume you're looking for path not URL.

Comment: @Zeshak Khattak, Ok, I am consider it for image. But, what is for several url for calling controller function's  ?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using this for the image path?

`base_url('path/to/image')`

Answer (score 0):

If having senario like
`ROOT
|____APPLICATION
|____ASSETS
|      |________ CSS
|      |________ JS
|      |________ IMG
|____SYSTEM`

then you can access the css as follows:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/getinfo.css"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/image.png"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The current accepted answer works fine, but it is not relative. For instance: if the website would be replaced from the root to a subdirectory, the url wouldn't work anymore.

More on this same topic I found here: [How can I display images with the Codeigniter php framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656894/how-can-i-display-images-with-the-codeigniter-php-framework)

The answer in that topic recommends not working with relative paths, but personally I would like to see this possible within modules (the MX-plugin for CodeIgniter).

So here's a possible way of working with relative paths I found:

```
 <?php $path = base_url(str_replace(FCPATH,"", __DIR__ )).'/'; ?>
```

Example usage:

```
<img src="<?php echo $path;?>../assets/img/myImage.png" />
```

for instance: if the this html would be used in /modules/mymodule/views/someviewfile.php the output will be yourdomain.com/modules/mymodule/assets/img/myImage.png